# Update query won't work in mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to execute a query in MySQL but it won't work. This is the query:

```
Update chambre set nombre_lit = 5 and prix = 10000 where code_ch = 2
```

If I execute this script it works:

```
Update chambre set  prix = 10000 where code_ch = 2
Update chambre set nombre_lit = 5  where code_ch = 2
```

But I want to use only one line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `COMMA` if you have multiple columns to update instead of `AND`

```
UPDATE chambre 
SET    nombre_lit = 5, 
       prix = 10000 
WHERE  code_ch = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:-

```
Update chambre set nombre_lit = 5 , prix = 10000 where code_ch = 2
```